Weird Blurring Effect When Moving Model in Viewport Shading
My mesh keeps having this weird blur effect in viewport shading whenever I move it or animate it.  I used the materials properties tab to color the model since I am not using any complicated textures, but whenever I move the object in viewport shading the colors will "shift" or blur then become sharp once I stop.
It's hard to explain, but it worsens when I zoom out, sometimes to the point of becoming unrecognizable with smaller details.  I've recorded a short video showing the problem with the central area of focus being the glasses and other head details.
I cannot find anything online for a solution, and have searched multiple times for similar problems but have drawn a blank.
Video link: https://youtu.be/SZZd8GDIPb8
File: 

You're using a pretty old version of Blender (2.92) and have you checked that you have the latest graphics drivers installed for your machine?

I've updated both Blender and my drivers.  If anything, it's actually made it worse.  Is this a problem with me using the materials manager to color the parts, or is it maybe a setting I have turned on?

I've never seen anything like it using Blender to be honest. Maybe share your Blend file using File > External Data > Pack Resources first to see whether it happens on anyone else's machine here? If the packed file is smaller than 30 Meg you can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it. Alternatively use an external file sharing site.

Alright, I'll do that once I get back to my home computer, thanks!

Adde the file to the post!

I agree with @Kid with Glasses that it's probably just the speed of your machine graphics trying to render a fast-moving object. For what it's worth it doesn't do it here on this fast PC and in any case I can't see that it would be noticeable during normal animation.  Just for your information the normals on the left fingers and the face of the glasses are inverted on your object. (Red with Face Orientation enabled on the Viewport overlays menu.) Select All in Edit mode then Shift-N to correct. The right lens will have to be flipped using Alt-N > Flip.

Thanks, I'll try that.  If it's connected to the issue, I use a 1070 I believe in my computer as a grahics card.  Also, unfortunately it does occur during animations as well, it was actually during mid-animating that I noticed it :/

If I understand you correctly, that is the Eevee engine that powers the material view processing. It might be rendering the samples slowly enough to make it to where you see each individual sample being rendered. With each sample the render gets clearer, but on the first sample, it usually is a little blurry, especially with high scale or detail in a noise texture for the material.

I tried changing the graphics engine but it didn't alter it, I'm wondering if this is just a computer hardware problem.  Although, my Yoga i7 laptop does it, too, so I am unsure.

Is there a way to nullify those effects?  It's the biggest problem I'm having right now and is stopping me from creating animations.  I could try my laptop, however I feel that my PC is stronger than the specs it has.

@SmartToaster4K I'd have to suggest disabling any extra checkboxes in the Render properties, and then just turn them back on when you render. That won't eradicate it completely, but it might help (a bit). Another thing I'd suggest: in the material properties, scroll down to Viewport Display, and make a preview color (no image or bump mapping). This will show that color (only) in the Solid viewport, which would, theoretically, eliminate the blurring you see. In the end, it would probably be faster to switch to Solid viewport mode to animate and then switch back when you are done.

I just tested out swapping to the Solid viewport and it seems to have entirely eliminated the problem, thank you!  It won't have the level of appearence the Viewport Shading has, but I can what I can do with it.  I could try animating in the Solid viewport and swapping back, but when the animation plays it still blurs.  I'm probably going to mess with the first method and see if the result looks good, and then I might see if I can test this problem on one of the better computers at my house to determine if it could also just be a graphics card issue.
